# Hmac in MIGS payment in php and Node.js different

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, hmac

I'm trying to convert the `MIGS payment gateway code` from `PHP` to `NODE.js`
Everything else is fine except this hmac hash code generation
`PHP CODE`

```
strtoupper(hash_hmac('SHA256',$this->hashInput, pack("H*",$this->secureHashSecret)));
```

`Javascript/NODE.js code`

```
var binKey = new Buffer(SecureSecret,"hex");

var hasheddata = new Buffer(    
    crypto.createHmac('SHA256',binKey).update(hashvalue).digest('hex')                            
).toString().toUpperCase();
```

hashInput and securesecret is same for both the above code , but i'm always getting different values .

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i messed up the Order of Hashvalue .. The code is working fine
So if anyone want to convert the same here it is.. Enjoy

Comment: Can you please post full source, am stuck and don't know what to do